# Como hacer consulta entre meses o fechas

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

estoy intentando realizar una consulta a mi tabla especificando, tomando un id , en especifico:

```
  $id=$_GET['id'];
        $Consult= "SELECT * FROM pagos_colegio WHERE id='$id' AND mes BETWEEN ('jan' AND 'Dec');
 ";
    $result= $conexion->query($Consult);
    if($fila = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {


    }
```

La idea es saber donde aparece este id entre esos meses, Gracias por anticipado.

Comment: Véase: http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo comprendo a tu pregunta seria esto

```
SELECT * FROM pagos_colegio WHERE id='$id' AND mes BETWEEN (DATE('2015-12-00') AND DATE('2015-12-00')+ INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ;
```

Esta consulta te enviara entre el intervalo de 1 mes

Comment: Gracias Marck y Miguel, por su guia , voy a probar...

Comment: Graciar Miguel tu solución me funciono, perfectamente.

Comment: que bueno que te funciono saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres consultar fechas tendrías que agregarle un campo DATE a tu tabla y hacer:
mes BETWEEN fecha1 AND fecha2
O si sólo quieres consultar si está entre ciertos meses podrías enumerarlos y colocar:
mes BETWEEN 1 AND 12.